# Multiple if in jQuery sciprt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have simple jQuery script on my website which resize my logo when I scroll my page down and return to some values when I back to top. Issue is that I can't setup different values for my logo for different page sizes. As I don't have experience not sure if my my "if" statements are correct. I also tried with "else with" but without results.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var logo = $('.hkb_header_logo img');
  var menuheight = jQuery('nav.navbar').height();
  var menutop = jQuery('#hkb_menu').offset().top;

  jQuery(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    var menuOffset = menutop - menuheight;

    if (menuOffset < 0) {
      menuOffset = 0;
    }

    if (scrollTop > menutop) {

      if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '60%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '60%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '-100px');
      }

      if (window.innerWidth < 1260) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '70%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '70%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      }

      if (window.innerWidth < 1320) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '85%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '85%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '-150px');
      } else {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '55%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '55%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      }
    } else if (scrollTop <= menuOffset) {
      if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '60%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '60%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      }

      if (window.innerWidth < 1260) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '70%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '70%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      }

      if (window.innerWidth < 1320) {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '85%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '85%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      } else {
        jQuery(logo).css('height', '100%');
        jQuery(logo).css('width', '100%');
        jQuery(logo).css('margin-top', '0px');
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: You're kinda close, but your inner-if statements all overwrite each other because they're all separate statements rather than a chain of if else if. But there's *gotta* be a better way to approach this than a giant if statement and a bunch of hardcoded values.

Comment: hi, probably there is better approach but I don't I am not familiar with jQuery. Do you know how to fix my code to do not overwrite each if?

Comment: make them all else ifs

Comment: I tried they not work

Comment: You probably did it incorrectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251798/discussion-between-majan-and-kevin-b).

Comment: FYI, if you're using `$` on the outer function you can also use it instead of `jQuery` inside.

Comment: Most of this can be handled with CSS. You rarely should put a bunch of CSS in your script. You can basically swap one class on an outer element or the body with your script and key off that for your logo styles.

Comment: remove al the "else" statements and specify the ranges properly: `if (window.innerWidth < 1320 && window.innerWidth >= 767) {`